# Why do my settings in iTerm2's Bash shell not translate into Tmux sessions?

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I installed Bash via Homebrew and when I type in `which bash` I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`. I also changed the default shell from Z to Bash as well and made custom color configurations.

When I create a new Tmux session, I noticed that all of that is gone and iTerm2 behaves as if I didn't install anything: the default shell is Z, there are no color configurations, and when I type `which bash` I get `/bin/bash`.

Why does this happen and how can I make them the same?

Comment: Newer macOS still has bash, so you just added a second

Comment: The default Bash was version 3.2 and I installed 5.2.12. Is that somehow relevant to how Tmux is behaving?